# Hobbled math processing on this site?

Tags: discussion

In a site about proof assistants, I'd expect to be able to format mathematics reasonably smoothly, but many things ( cases, newline, and set-brackets are just two of the things that I've found so far ) the processing is...unexpected. I would hope that

```
$$
U = \{ 3, 5 \} \\
f(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ $t < 0$ }\\
t^2 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
```

would produce output that looks like this:

[image]

when in fact it produces
$$
U = \{ 3, 5 \} \\
f(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ $t < 0$ }\\
t^2 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

which is a little disappointing. It also does this very slowly. Was there some reason to not just copy the infrastructure from math stackexchange?

Comment: Well...that's embarrassing. 45 minutes ago, when I wrote this, the math-processing was removing the brackets on the set, and putting the case-expression all on one line with no line-breaks. Maybe this was a javascript glitch or something. I'm leaving this here in hopes that someone can explain the kind of junk I was seeing.

Comment: You should have screenshotted the bad rendering, because now I only see two perfectly rendered formulas side by side :(

Comment: If I'd have known it was transitory, I wouldn't have bothered asking the question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your browsers haven't loaded the math CSS file yet. This is a common phenomenon for both mathjax (CommonHTML render engine) and katex. If this persists, you can try opening the developer's tools in your browser to see if there is some network issue loading some assets.

Comment: I'm sure this is correct -- everything was running VERY slowly while this mess was going on. :(